# Multiple Linear Regression 100% Accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am getting 100% accuracy in multiple linear regression. I am following one tutorial of last year. He is not getting 100% accuracy on the same model but I am getting now. Seems weird to me. Here's my code. Am I am doing it right or there's something wrong in my code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


dataset = pd.read_csv('M_Regression.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, :1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, x_test, Y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

#regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train,Y_train)

#Prediction
y_pred = reg.predict(x_test)

print(str(y_test) + " - " + str(y_pred))
```

Answer (score 2):

Linear Regression have simple numbers it is common to have 100% accuracy on large dataset. Try with other datasets once. I tried your code i got 1.0 Accuracy on it.

Answer (score 1):

To check the accuracy of your model, you could try printing the r2 score of your test sample. Something among the lines of :

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print(r2_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

if you still have issues with the score. You could try removing the "random_state=0" to check if you still have 100% accuracy with several train/test data sets.

Comment: I removed the randomstate but values are way off now

`[[   542.05]
 [ 20229.59]
 [162597.7 ]
 [134615.46]
 [ 23640.93]
 [ 61136.38]
 [ 64664.71]
 [ 93863.75]
 [114523.61]
 [ 91749.16]
 [144372.41]
 [ 15505.73]
 [ 73994.56]
 [     0.  ]
 [ 67532.53]] [[ 5.42050000e+02]
 [ 2.02295900e+04]
 [ 1.62597700e+05]
 [ 1.34615460e+05]
 [ 2.36409300e+04]
 [ 6.11363800e+04]
 [ 6.46647100e+04]
 [ 9.38637500e+04]
 [ 1.14523610e+05]
 [ 9.17491600e+04]
 [ 1.44372410e+05]
 [ 1.55057300e+04]
 [ 7.39945600e+04]
 [-1.56232766e-11]
 [ 6.75325300e+04]]`

Comment: the random_state only fixes the way the train_test_split shuffles X into X_train and X_test. If your model is robust then it shouldn't diverge like that (I guess that they are not normal). Did you try printing the r2 score ?

Comment: yes i did and got 1.0 but it's hard to believe i am new so don't know.